# Which approach should I use to invoke a method at a regular interval?

Tags: cocoa, nstimer

I can invoke a function on a regular interval using either NSTimer or having a thread wake up at regular intervals.  The two approaches will behave essentially the same:

```
        timer = [ NSTimer
                 scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                 target:self
                 selector:@selector(doSomething)
                 userInfo:nil
                 repeats:NO
                 ];
```

and

```
 @autoreleasepool {
        BOOL continueProcessingQueue = YES;
        while (continueProcessingQueue) {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
            NSDate *curtainTime = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10];
            NSDate *currentTime = [[NSDate alloc] init];

            while (continueProcessingQueue && ([currentTime compare:curtainTime] != NSOrderedDescending)) {
                if ([self.processThread isCancelled] == YES) {
                    continueProcessingQueue = NO;
                }
                [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
                currentTime = [[NSDate alloc] init];
            }
        }
    }
```

Using timers seems much simpler.  Are there situations where the second approach is preferable to using a timer?

Answer (score 0):

a) when you don't track the active status of the secondary thread. once the thread exits, your timer goes with it, meaning your timer may not deliver all the messages you expect it to.

b) when your worker thread is not actually polling the run loop (long tasks), and/or when your secondary thread's work returns control to the run loop infrequently and you need higher accuracy of the milestones/progress you post to other threads. if your secondary thread is  idle/waiting most of the time, then this is not much of an issue.

In fact, you really should not be using either approach above in most scenarios.

Comment: I have trouble understanding a few things: What do you refer as secondary thread? The thread inside which the timer is launched?  What do you mean by polling the run loop here in the examples we are discussing?  Last: you suggest that neither approach is appropriate in most scenarios.  Assuming my doSomething is performing a synchronous POST and the frequency at which I want to do these is every minute or so, what would be a good approach if neither of those above?  Currently I am using the timer approach inside a dispatch_async statement that allows the timer to run while in the background.

Comment: @user91208 a) the secondary thread in the program you provided above is the one which does the work and calls back to the main thread periodically. b) waiting/running the run loop. run loops wait after the thread's work is performed and control is returned to them, then they wake up and do more work (or they can exit). so rather than 'poll', 'run' is a better word choice. but 'run' just means "lay idle until it's time to work". every cocoa level thread has a run loop -- the run loop is what your timer attaches to.

Comment: @user91208 c) for the scenario you describe, just adopt `NSURLConnectionDelegate`, create an *asynchronous* `NSURLConnection` -- of course, ensure there is only one at a time to avoid redundant work. then your progress/info is returned to the delegate.